# Position of capacitor in a full wave rectifier circuit?

Tags: capacitor, rectifier

Can a capacitor be connected after the load resistance in the following circuit: [image: Full wave rectifier with capacitor filter]

Why or why not?

Comment: What research have you done ?

Answer (score 1):

Any load that requires low ripple voltage will benefit from the capacitor being as close to it as possible. You have to think in terms of the wires having both resistance and inductance - those (usually) unwanted parasitic components can make ripple worse.

Having the capacitor after the load (as per the diagram in the question) is worse than having it before the load. Apart from anything else it is inconvenient to do it this way - most engineers would test a power supply with the capacitor attached and add loads afterwards.

If we are talking mains frequencies of 50/60 Hz then a few cm either way isn't going to make much of a difference to low power circuits but, at higher powers it can mean problems with ripple voltages.

Comment: I understand. Could you also tell me what other impact it would have, if I were asked to answer the same question technically (I have an exam coming up)?

Comment: Well, if the circuit shown in your question was a full-wave AM radio receiver envelope detector (and there is no reason from your diagram to suppose it isn't) I would give the same answer. Ask yourself - what is the capacitor intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the best performance of a ripple and EMC case you should put the capacitor as close as practical possible to the switch, hence here the diodes cathode. In that way you don't add on any unnecessary parasitic with unwanted effects.  It will also give the shortest loop patch for the noise.

However in a power distributed network where the load is sensitive and the wires to the load from the power source is significant it may be good to put some decoupling capacitors at the load. However this only yields if the loads in the network are active.